# XSLT 1.0 and tokenizing attributes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, tokenize

*[edit] post updated with revised XML and desired output as detailed in Vincent Biragnet's answer and comments.*

I'm trying to put together some code to convert XML data into a text based meta file. I'm having no luck getting it to spit out desired output and am currently kinda stuck, so any help would be appreciated.

XSLT 1.0 does not make tokenizing easy and that's where I got stuck: I would like to treat @syn as a CSV string and break it apart when needed.

I'm working with the following XML data (please note that all nodes, except for the <Meta> node, in this XML file can have any name.)

```
<Meta>
    <Subject>
        <People>
            <Jane_Doe syn="janie, jd" />
            <John_Doe/>
        </People>
        <Object>
            <Table>
                <Leg/>
            </Table>
            <Chair syn="seat" />
        </Object>
    </Subject>
    <Test1>
        <Test2 syn="testy"/>
        <Test3>
            <Test4/>
        </Test3>
    </Test1>
</Meta>
```

This XML needs to be converted so the output looks this:

```
[Subject]
    [People]
        Jane_Doe
            {janie}
            {jd}
        John_Doe
    [Object]
        [Table]
            Leg
        Chair
            {seat}
[Test1]
    Test2
        {testy}
    [Test3]
        Test4
```

My current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Meta"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child::*"><xsl:call-template name="master"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="master">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@syn"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                [<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>]
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@syn"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenize" match="@syn">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                {<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>}
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    {<xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>}
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to get exactly your output with XSLT 1.0, but you can use the mecanism you tried. Here is an XSLT 1.0 that output with the indentation :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Meta">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="depth" select="0"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$depth > 0">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>            
                <xsl:call-template name="addSpace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nb" select="$depth"></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>                
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position() > 1">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>                            
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>                
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@syn|*">
            <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>       
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenize" match="@syn">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="depth" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="addSpace">
            <xsl:with-param name="nb" select="$depth"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
                <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="addSpace">
        <xsl:param name="nb"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="$nb >1 ">
            <xsl:call-template name="addSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="nb" select="$nb - 1"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>            
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result with your input is :

```
[Subject]
 [People]
  Jane_Doe
   {janie}
   {jd}
  John_Doe
 [Object]
  [Table]
   Leg
  Chair
   {seat}
```

Note the difference with your output : the `table` element is between bracket because it has one or more children.

Comment: Like what you've done here. It spits out the result nicely. Except for when I add some nodes like this:
`<Meta>
 <Subject>
  <People>
   <Jane_Doe syn="janie, jd" />
   <John_Doe/>
  </People>
  <Object>
   <Table>
    <Leg/>
   </Table>
   <Chair syn="seat" />
  </Object>
 </Subject>
 <Test1>
  <Test2 syn="testy"/>
  <Test3><Test4/></Test3>
 </Test1>
</Meta>`

If you run this, you'll notice that the Test1 node is not starting on the right line. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Daktari, consider to edit your question to show us the additional input document, assuming it consists of several lines the comment does not show.

Comment: @daktari : I updated the XSLT to take your comment into account. As Martin pointed out : maybe you should add this new XML input in your question.

Comment: @Vincent Biragnet Thank you ever so much--exactly the result I'm after. And yes, a lot trickier with XSLT 1.0. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

you were pretty much there, just got brackets around wrong thing causing error!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Meta"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child::*"><xsl:call-template name="master"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="master">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@syn"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                [<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>]
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@syn"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenize" match="@syn">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                {<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>}
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                {<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>}
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, I realised that too shortly after posting. And then noticed there still were some issues. Thankfully all resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:param name="lf" select="'&#10;'"/>
  <xsl:param name="start-indent" select="'    '"/>
  <xsl:param name="br1" select="'['"/>
  <xsl:param name="br2" select="']'"/>
  <xsl:param name="br3" select="'{'"/>
  <xsl:param name="br4" select="'}'"/>
  <xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Meta" priority="10">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="''"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent, local-name(), $lf)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@syn">
      <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, $start-indent)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent, $br1, local-name(), $br2, $lf)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, $start-indent)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@syn">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $sep))">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space($text)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent, $br3, normalize-space($text), $br4, $lf)"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent, $br3, normalize-space(substring-before($text, $sep)), $br4, $lf)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="$indent"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $sep)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. You've also taken an interesting approach. Vincent Biragnet's code is doing the job for me, but I'm having a good look at your code so I can learn from it. Thanks for your time.